# Как запретить ввод количества символов в массив меньшего, чем размер массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, char, символы

Имеется динамический массив символов:

```
char* massiv = new char[amount];
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в этот массив нельзя было ввести символы, общее количество которых меньше, чем указано в **amount**.

То есть, пользователь должен ввести символы в массив не используя клавишу **Enter**, и когда эта клавиша будет нажата (подразумевая окончание ввода символов), программа считает количество введённых символов и, если оно меньше **amount**, то программа выдаёт сообщение об ошибке (ну или завершается).

Вот так сделать не получилось:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        cin >> massiv[i];
        if (massiv[i] == '\n') {
            if (i < amount - 1) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Программа ожидает ввод символов пока счётчик **i** не достигнет последнего своего значения. На нажатие клавиши **Enter** программе без разницы.

Comment: Это я знаю. Фактически, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы цикл обрывался при вводе клавиши Enter, а затем если количество введенных символов равно размеру массива, то программа продолжала работу

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь считать из буфера ввода информацию до ближайшего переноса строки (символа \n) при помощи [std::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). А потом просто сравнить количество символов в считанной информации:

```
int main()
{
    static int64_t amount = 10; // Твоё количество символов
    
    std::string content{};
    std::getline(std::cin, content);
    
    if (content.size() < amount)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // .... Твой остальной код

    return 0;
}
```

Рабочий код: [*кликабельно*](https://godbolt.org/z/W6bWanf83)

Comment: В моём задании необходимо использовать именно динамический массив

Comment: `std::` для `int64_t` стоит добавить.

Comment: @tocic это хедер cstdint, так что вовсе не обязательно

Comment: Этот идентификатор же [по стандарту](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint.syn) в `namespace std`. Если работает [в одной реализации](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2f8342a3a57fb157d881c6a2d42a917d20e413f8/stl/inc/cstdint#L25), то не значит, что будет работать в другой. См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13643019/6944845.

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь оставить цикл с проверкой

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const std::size_t amount = 3;
    char* array = new char[amount + 1]{};

    std::size_t size = 0;
    int chr;
    while (true)
    {
        chr = std::cin.get();
        if (chr == '\n' || size == amount)
            break;

        array[size++] = chr;
    }

    if (chr != '\n' || size != amount)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid characters count. Size of input must be " + std::to_string(amount));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Если готов рискнуть и поработать с std::string другой ответ в помощь

Comment: Ну почему сразу рискнуть? Динамические массивы и голые указатели - это Сишный код, к тому же гораздо более рисковый, чем использование специально для этого предназначенных объектов из STD. Всё таки тег С++ стоит, а не С

Comment: @ComeInRage это просто шутка юмора такая)